# Import a Static HTML Vue Component inside another Vue Component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

**Context** :
I have a vue component(s) that are stored in an S3 repository in the form of static HTML (name it `child`). Now I want to import these vue components inside another Vue Component inside a Nuxt Project (name it `parent`). So it's gonna be a page where the content is dynamically rendered

**Current workaround** :
In the `parent` component, I have a snippets like this :

```
<div id="content-test" v-html="content"/>
```

Where `content` is a HTML string that is rendered by `child` component

**Current issue** :
The styling for the `parent` component is broken. Probably caused by some scripts/css that runs in the `child` component

**Some other workaround I've done / think about :**

- Render the `child` component inside iframe : Not good, because I want the content of the `child` to be SEO-friendly
- Export `child` as a `npm` package / repository so that it can be used in `parent` component dynamically : Not good, because the `node_modules` of the parent component might grows large if the `child` component is too large

Do anyone ever had this issue and how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: "Not good, because the node_modules of the parent component might grows large" - this should be the last concern. Export the component as Vue lib, it won't have its own dependencies

Comment: Hi @EstusFlask thanks for answering. Could you please explain what do you mean by "won't have it's own dependencies?"

Comment: A library will use Vue and possibly other dependency from a project that uses it if dep versions match, and so won't make node_modules bigger